# How can I get the full path to image src for eleventy-img if I use glob collections?

Tags: filepath, glob, eleventy

### Problem:

I'm using the *shortcode* in `/technical-seo/using-science-philosophy-organize-semantic-web.md` `{% image "grocery-isle.jpg", "Google Photos – Aisle 5, Faversham Sainsbury’s", "320, 640, 1024", "img-responsive" %}`

```
`TemplateContentRenderError` was thrown
[11ty] > (./technical-seo/using-science-philosophy-organize-semantic-web.md)
  EleventyShortcodeError: Error with Nunjucks shortcode `image`

`Template render error` was thrown
[11ty] > ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/denverpr/repositories/yada-11ty-themesgrocery-isle.jpg'
```

It's an image folder in each glob collection. I need the collection path to be included. The true path is `/home/denverpr/repositories/yada-11ty-themes/technical-seo/images/grocery-isle.jpg`

#### My current structure:

```
├── technical-seo
    ├── create-jump-to-links-serp.md
    ├── ecommerce-site-structure-for-semantic-search.md
    ├── images
    │   ├── grocery-isle.jpg
    │   ├── optimize-local-seo.jpg
    │   ├── science-semantic-web.png
    │   ├── serp-jump-to-links-1.png
    │   ├── serp-jump-to-links-2.png
    │   ├── serp-jump-to-links-3.png
    │   └── serp-jump-to-links.png
    ├── index.njk
    ├── optimizing-local-search.md
    ├── technical-seo.11data.js
    └── using-science-philosophy-organize-semantic-web.md
```

### My `eleventy-img` code:

```
module.exports = function(src, alt, widths, sizes, classattr) {
  // src input same as 'normal' site-relative path for convenience, so add base path:
  src = path.dirname(__dirname) + src;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the error message, it shows that it's looking for the image at `/home/denverpr/repositories/yada-11ty-themesgrocery-isle.jpg` but not finding anything, which makes sense given that the image is located at `/home/denverpr/repositories/yada-11ty-themes/technical-seo/images/grocery-isle.jpg`.

You can also see why that incorrect path is generated. `src` will be `/home/denverpr/repositories/yada-11ty-themes` (the dirname thing) + `grocery-isle.jpg`.

To fix this, you can either update the image shortcode with the full path to the image, or add in the correct path to your image code. The best approach will depend on your specific situation.

Approach 1 - update shortcode (and also fix the generated path):

```
{% image "technical-seo/images/grocery-isle.jpg", ... %}
```

```js
module.exports = function(src, alt, widths, sizes, classattr) {
  // src input same as 'normal' site-relative path for convenience, so add base path:
  src = path.dirname(__dirname) + "/" + src;
```

Approach 2 - fix path in image code:

```js
module.exports = function(src, alt, widths, sizes, classattr) {
  // src input same as 'normal' site-relative path for convenience, so add base path:
  src = path.dirname(__dirname) + "/technical-seo/images/" + src;
```

Comment: I’ve been trying to figure out a way to declare the file path as 11ydata in each directory but I don’t know how to make that very able to discover by the image that JS file and read the folders Json file or JavaScript

Comment: @DenverProphitJr. You might be able to automatically discover the path directory using [`page` data values](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/nunjucks/#access-to-page-data-values), possibly with [`this.page.inputPath`](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-eleventy-supplied/#page-variable-contents).